# Facebook erased notes after saying they wouldn't do that

Tags: facebook

Here is an official announcement from Facebook from about the beginning of October:

> Creating and editing Facebook notes will be unavailable after October 31, 2020. Any published notes will stay published on Facebook profiles. However, any unpublished drafts will be deleted.

Note in particular this:

> Any published notes will stay published on Facebook profiles.

But that is false. They're gone.

Is there any way to find Facebook notes published before October 31, 2020, or have all of them been permanently destroyed?

Comment: Thank you I was just looking for info on this. I have a note in a pinned post at the top of my Facebook Page, and this one is still there, so maybe that's what they meant. And I can't edit it or anything. But I can't access to other Notes.